# ProGuard on Android missing reference on class that is not in my project

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

So, I have ProGUard on, and it is giving me warning:

```
Warning: com.bestclass.childrenclass.encryption.CryptoObscurifier: can't find referenced class com.facebook.crypto.Entity
Warning: com.bestclass.childrenclass.CryptoObscurifier: can't find referenced class com.facebook.crypto.Crypto
```

But the problem is that this CryptoObscurifier is not a part of my no.class.class.

Is there some kind of cache on ProGuard?
Can i bust it some how?

I know i can add

`-dontwarn com.facebook.**`

But im trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: What library is this? If you don't know paste all your dependencies.

Comment: Its not a library. Im trying to remove facebook conceal, and that is gone from my dependencies. But for some reason CryptoObscurifier is still there, and it is in my project files. My project is bestclass.childrenclass.

Comment: So maybe it is still in `import` statements? Or remove build folder and rebuild the project again?

Comment: Didnt work to remove build folders, and there is nothing in import